# How to make IDE to understand that, the object exactly not null after method call

Tags: android, annotations, kotlin

I am using android studio with Kotlin language

[image]

and when I call the function above, its warning to check null state of "obj"

[image]

How its possible to make IDE (Android Studio) to understand that after some method call, the (passed) object exactly not null... thanks

Comment: Why don't you go for a null check? rather than make IDE understand

Comment: There are a few ways, I would need to see more of the code to tell you what makes more sense, or you can do your own work starting here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html. BTW the method isNotNull does not offer much of an advantage readability-wise in my opinion.

Comment: Why don't you go for a null check?

Answer: Just want to make null check statements more shorter and quick call this fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an opaque `isNotNull` method call, which Kotlin can't (and shouldn't) reason about, use one of the idioms native to the language, such as:

```
value?.let {
    val response = it.response
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for response. I did as as suggested but again the IDE warns to use the "it" with safe "?" mark.

val response:Response? = value.let {  val response: Response? = it.response }

Comment: aaahh, OK, sorry, I forgot the ? at start

Thanks

Comment: I didn't suggest to write `val response = value?.let [...]`, but to put the entire logic you're about to perform on the `response` inside the `let` block.

Comment: But whether  there is no way to do null check with high level functions in general way?

Comment: Not in the way you wanted. Imagine your `isNotNull` function called another one, involved dynamic method dispatch (so it doesn't even know which method it's calling), and that other method made the decision? It's just not amenable to static analysis.